# How to return 404 when resource is not found, instead of HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this controller:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class MetricsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:update]

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      render json: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find_by(site: params[:site_id], post_id: params[:post_id])
  end

  def post_params
    params.fetch(:post, {})
  end
end
```

And I would like to know how can I return `404` not found when `@post` is `nil`. Right now `@post.update` raises an error if `@post` is `nil`, and the response is a HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of `ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#find_by!` which raises an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` instead of `nil` when the record isn't found, and then use a `rescue_from` block to handle the error.

```rb
class MetricsController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
    # it is up to you create RecordNotFoundSerializer
    serializer = RecordNotFoundSerializer.new exception

    render json: serializer.to_json, status: :not_found
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find_by(site: params[:site_id], post_id: params[:post_id])
  end
end
```

You can also extract the error handling to a base controller (`ApplicationController` in you example) and centralize error handling there.

Comment: Are you sure this works? Cause the following error is raising: `uninitialized constant ApplicationController::RecordNotFoundSerializer`

Comment: Yes! `RecordNotFoundSerializer` is up to you to implement or even throw it away completely. The way you turn the error/exception into JSON is up to you.

Comment: Yeah, I got that after thinking a little more haha

Answer (score 1):

You can add a check and return not_found if `@post` is nil & inorder to prevent your app from crashing you can handle other errors by adding `rescue` block and return your desired from there

```
def update
 return render json: YOUR_ERROR, status: :not_found unless @post
 if @post.update(post_params)
   render json: @post
 else
   render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
 end
rescue StandardError => e
  render json: e, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check for `@post` to your controller action and return a 404 if it's `nil`:

```rb
def update
  if @post
    if @post.update(post_params)
      render json: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  else
    render json: YourCustomJsonError, status: 404
  end
end
```